# How do i change an object through the use of pointers?

Tags: c++, object, pointers, reference

```
#include "Visit.h"
class Patient
{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string IC;
    List<Visit> *visitList;
    List<MC> mcList;
public:
    Patient();
    Patient(std::string, std::string);
    void addVisit(Visit); 
    List<Visit> *getVisitList();
};

//End of Patient.h

#include "Patient.h"

Patient::Patient()
{
    visitList = new List<Visit>();
}

Patient::Patient(std::string ic, std::string n) : name(n), IC(ic)
{
    visitList = new List<Visit>();
}

void Patient::addVisit(Visit v)
{
    visitList->add(v);
}

List<Visit> * Patient::getVisitList()
{
    return visitList;
}
//End of Patient.cpp

class Visit
{
private:
    __int64 time;
    double cost;
    bool xRayStatus = false;
public:
    Visit();
    Visit(__int64, double);
    void addXRay();
    bool getXRayStatus();
};
//End of Visit.h

#include "Visit.h"

Visit::Visit() {
}

Visit::Visit(__int64 t, double c) : time(t), cost(c) {
}

void Visit::addXRay()
{
    xRayStatus = true;
}

bool Visit::getXRayStatus()
{
    return xRayStatus;
};

//End of Visit.cpp

int main()
{
        int pos;
        Visit v(/*current time, cost*/);
        Patient p()
        unordered_map<string, Patient> patientMap;
        string IC;
        getline(cin,IC);
        Patient p(IC, "John");
        patientMap.insert({IC, p});

        Patient *pc;
        Visit *vc;
        pos = patientMap[IC].getVisitList()->getLength();
        pc = &patientMap[IC];

        pc->addVisit(v); //Debugger shows patientMap[IC].getVisitList()->getLength() becomes 2

        pc->getVisitList()->get(pos).addXRay(); //patientMap[IC].getVistList()->get(0).getXRayStatus() still false

        vc = &patientMap[IC].getVisitList()->get(pos); 
        vc->addXRay(); //patientMap[IC].getVistList()->get(0).getXRayStatus() still false
}
```

How do i make that getXRayStatus true? It seems odd to me that i can add items into the list but not carry out other functions like vc->addXRay.
vc itself shows true but the change isn't reflected on my map.
pc somehow is able to add Visits and show the change on the map.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title, make the pointer point to another object?

Comment: Is your `List` class broken? (I.e. its `get()` returns by value?)

Comment: @KerrekSB My List class is by pointer implementation. get() return Node->item;

Comment: @KateGregory Is there a way to change these dummy copies?

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, i'm having hell because of this dummy copy problem. Is there anything i can do without changing my List class? I have other parts of the program using it. My X-Ray is in Visit as the patient may have multiple visits and treatments, conditions are all in that Visit object.

Comment: @KateGregory I did visitList->get(pos).addXRay();
 and used a debugger to step in the methods. It showed the change on a "this" in local view but when it got out of the method visit::addXRay() , it did not show the change; argh

Comment: @KateGregory Ahh yeah i know what you mean now, for now i'll just stick with changing the copy, remove the original and adding the copy. What do you recommend my class diagram to be for such a case? Many treatments, conditions, medicine in a Visit. Many visits in a patient eh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an extended comment conversation, the asker has asked for general redesign help to avoid the problems caused by working with a `Visit` copy from `get()`. My redesign suggestions are:

- stop using `List`. Whether you wrote it yourself or got it somewhere else, it's surely more than you need. Use `std::vector<>` as the collection class of first choice, and change to something else only when you need it.
- don't keep pointers to your collections in `Patient` unless they are likely to be enormous memory hogs. Have vectors as member variables. This will save you having to write a lot of cleanup code.
- Stop keeping solid `Visit` objects in the collections. Use `make-shared()` or `make_unique` to get yourself smart pointers to `visit` objects that are on the heap. Keep these pointers in the vectors and you can deference them to change the real values in the real visits out on the heap
- consider adding a date and time or visit number to `Visit` since at the moment it's not clear to me how you find a specific visit when there is more than one
- set properties in things before you put them in collections. Your `main` knows all about the inside of a `Visit` (not that I approve of that) but has `Patient` create an empty one and then jumps through hoops trying to get hold of it and change some of its properties. Why not have `Patient` set those properties? Or have `main()` create a `Visit`, fill in all the properties, and then hand it to `Patient` saying "here, add this to your collection"? What you're doing now is so much harder than it needs to be.

Finally, find a tutorial, book, or online course that works for you and gets you clear on the difference between objects and pointers, good reasons for using pointers, the need for destructors (you have none at the moment) and for good measure explains the collection classes in `std::` and elsewhere. Tutorials and architectural advice are not a good fit for the Q&A mechanism of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

In the `List<Visit>` you are keeping instances of `Visit`s. When you are setting the xRayStatus you are changing the status of the local `Visit` copy you get from the list, not to the actual object in the list.

Comment: So how do i make the change in the actual object in the list?